# javamail store.isconnected() function bug

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I came across a very strange bug in javamail store isConnected() function. I am using it in my android application the reconnect to store if connection is dropped.

```
if (!store.isConnected()) store.connect(host, username, password);
```

But, when connection is dropped, this function returns **true** the first time it is called, and **false** the second time it is called. That means that the above code will not trigger store.connect if store is not connected, but this code:

```
if (!store.isConnected()) store.connect(host, username, password);
else if (!store.isConnected()) store.connect(host, username, password);
```

will reconnect the store because of the second call to isConnected() function that return false.

I don't know if I explained the bug good enought.
I would like to know if this is a known behavior or not. Maybe, I am doing something wrong. Or, maybe there is a better way to reconnect store if it is disconnected.

Thank you in advance!

*Edit:*

This code:

```
LOGGER.warning("START1");
if (!store.isConnected()) {
    LOGGER.warning("START1 CONN");
    store.connect(host, username, password);
    LOGGER.warning("END1 CONN");
}
LOGGER.warning("END1");
LOGGER.warning("START2");
if (!store.isConnected()) {
    LOGGER.warning("START2 CONN");
    store.connect(host, username, password);
    LOGGER.warning("END2 CONN");
}
LOGGER.warning("END2");
```

outputs this in javamail debug:

```
03-29 15:52:13.162: W/ShowMailbox(2063): START1
03-29 15:52:15.238: I/System.out(2063): IMAP DEBUG: IMAPProtocol noop
03-29 15:52:15.238: I/System.out(2063): A57 NOOP
03-29 15:52:15.242: I/System.out(2063): DEBUG: IMAPStore connection dead
03-29 15:52:15.242: I/System.out(2063): DEBUG: IMAPStore cleanup, force true
03-29 15:52:15.242: I/System.out(2063): DEBUG: IMAPStore cleanup done
03-29 15:52:22.810: W/ShowMailbox(2063): END1
03-29 15:52:24.762: W/ShowMailbox(2063): START2
03-29 15:52:34.033: W/ShowMailbox(2063): START2 CONN
03-29 15:52:36.369: I/System.out(2063): * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE STARTTLS] Courier-IMAP ready. Copyright 1998-2008 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for distribution information.
03-29 15:52:36.369: I/System.out(2063): A0 CAPABILITY
...
03-29 15:52:37.857: I/System.out(2063): A3 OK LOGIN Ok.
03-29 15:52:38.053: I/System.out(2063): IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: PLAIN
03-29 15:52:39.297: W/ShowMailbox(2063): END2 CONN
03-29 15:52:40.885: W/ShowMailbox(2063): END2
```

It looks like the first call to isConnected() is executed but returning true even if store is not connected and second isConnected() is not executed at all!? But it executes connect() function!?

I am really confused. And a little scared... :)

Comment: store.isConnected sends a NOP command to the server.  If that succeeds, it returns true.  Of course, the server can choose to drop the connection right after that, but that seems unlikely.  What does the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show when this happens?

Comment: how to debug in eclipse in android application?

Comment: @milosh Follow the link that Bill has kindly provided.

Comment: @Bill Shannon I have edited my answer with debug info

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using? In the debug output it should include the version number at the beginning.

Comment: @Bill Shannon JavaMail version 1.4.1 downloaded from https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/. I could not find newer version for android.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into a bug that was fixed in JavaMail 1.4.2.  You should be able to use the [newest version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) along with the additionnal.jar and activation.jar files.

Comment: If I use new javax.mail.jar file I have a problem with [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq-135477.html#castmultipart) and I do not understand from FAQ how to solve it. I can not get MultiPart object. What they suggest: Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader()) is not working.

Comment: What do you mean "can not get"?  This sounds like a new problem and should probably be in a new question.  Don't forget to include the code you're using, the exception you're getting, and the debug output.

Answer (score 0):

You can run into such a problem when sharing same IMAPStore object from different threads and having one connection in the pool. So think carrefully the way the store is used concurrently.